# Kotlin safe args direction is not generating

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation

I have just created a new project in Kotlin and I wanted to add navigation and safe args in it.

I have created 2 fragment (DishListFragment, DishDetailFragment) and an nav graph with action to one fragment to another in it. I have added one button to my first fragment and set a on click listener using view binding:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.deneme.setOnClickListener {
            val action = DishListFragmentDirections.actionDishListFragmentToDishDetailFragment()
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }

    }
```

but when I try to create a direction action named `DishListFragmentDirections` android studio giving me red errors saying:

```
Unresolved reference: DishListFragmentDirections
```

and says I should create `DishListFragmentDirections` class.

**Things I have tried:**

Into my app level `build.gradle`, I have added:

```
implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.safe.args.generator)
implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.safe.args.gradle.plugin)
```

I have tried invalidating caches and rebuilding my project but nothing helped me. I have tried doing things in doc but I think they have changed structure or something.

**Module** `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.fragment)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.safe.args.generator)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.safe.args.gradle.plugin)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
}
```

**Project** `build.gradle.kts`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid) apply false
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? You have mentioned how you have attempted to fix your issue, which is great, but you haven't told us what the issue is. Do you get an compile error? Does the app crash?

Comment: I have updated my question according to your comment @AlexT the problem is DishListFragmentDirections is not generated by kotlin itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/use-graph/safe-args#enable) section

1. Add classpath

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.androidx.navigation.safe.args.gradle.plugin)
    }
}
```

2. Add plugin

```
plugins {
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
}
```

The version in `libs.versions.toml` file

```
androidx-navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "navigationVersion" }
```

3. Sync and build project

> You must have `android.useAndroidX=true` in your gradle.properties file

Comment: I cannot add plugin because as you can see in my both buil.gradle files plugins are starts with alias(....) but you suggest me to put id(...). I have tried turning all id or writing safeargs with alias both did not worked. And yes I already have android.useAndroidX=true in my gradle.properties.

Comment: @KaanBinen `alias` and `id` can be in plugin section in the same time